# What if two plates charged with different charges are placed face to face?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-circuits, electricity, capacitance

I'm asking this question because I can't solve it even if I ask a lot of smart people. (Please understand that I don't speak smoothly because I use a translator. I'm korean student..)
In the next picture
The entire electrode plates 1 and electrode plate 3 connected by wires are charged with Q1.
The entire electrode plate 2 and electrode plate 4 connected by the wire are charged with Q2.
Plate 1 and plate 2 face each other.
Plate 3 and plate4 face each other
The question is how much charge is induced in each plate.
[image]
(The way I approached to solve the problem is as follows.) Because it is a different type of problem from a typical capacitor problem, I tried to solve the problem by leaving the charge on the top and bottom surfaces of the plates as unknown, respectively.
The conditions I used to solve the problem are: 1. Conservation of charge amount 2. The electric field inside the metal must be zero through Gaussian law 3. The potential difference between the two pair of plate is the same and the distance is three times, so the amount of charge induced on the inner surface of the two plates in each capacitor is three times (at V=Ed)

Using the above relationship to solve the equations, the amount of charge induced on the inner surface of the two plates could be calculated. However, there is no way to find the amount of charge distributed on the outer surface of the plate due to the lack of one equation, so I ask this question.